# Joomla SEF URL Issues on several sites

Tags: joomla3.0

I am running into an issue on several sites where the urls are "nesting" other links in the main url structure.

For example: https://retrolube.com/blog/five-benefits-of-new-tires-for-your-vehicle/blog/five-signs-your-vehicle-needs-new-tires/contact/blog/five-signs-your-vehicle-needs-new-tires/contact/blog/five-signs-your-vehicle-needs-new-tires

We are running K2, RS SEO, and JAmp. I have K2 Set to "Enable advanced SEF for K2 URLs"

These are only showing up with an auto crawl from RS SEO. It is creating more than 1000 links! They are unpublished but added to the site map! Is there a way to fix or prevent this?

---

htaccess file contents with extra comments removed

```
IndexIgnore *
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# Block any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
# Block any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root home page
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
#

## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php

# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.

## BEGIN EXPIRES CACHING - JCH OPTIMIZE ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive on

# Perhaps better to whitelist expires rules? Perhaps.
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"

# cache.appcache needs re-requests in FF 3.6 (thanks Remy ~Introducing HTML5)
  ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest "access plus 0 seconds"

# Your document html
  ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 0 seconds"

# Data
  ExpiresByType text/xml "access plus 0 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/xml "access plus 0 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/json "access plus 0 seconds"

# Feed
  ExpiresByType application/rss+xml "access plus 1 hour"
  ExpiresByType application/atom+xml "access plus 1 hour"

# Favicon (cannot be renamed)
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 week"

# Media: images, video, audio
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType video/ogg "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType audio/ogg "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType video/mp4 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType video/webm "access plus 1 month"

# HTC files (css3pie)
  ExpiresByType text/x-component "access plus 1 month"

# Webfonts
  ExpiresByType application/font-ttf "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType font/opentype "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/font-woff "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/font-woff2 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 month"

# CSS and JavaScript
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"

  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header append Cache-Control "public"
  </IfModule>

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/font
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/font-truetype
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/font-ttf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/font-otf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/font-opentype
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/font-woff
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/font-woff2
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/woff
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/woff2
# For Olders Browsers Which Can't Handle Compression
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
</IfModule>
## END EXPIRES CACHING - JCH OPTIMIZE ##


# SEO Fixes
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

## BEGIN EXPIRES CACHING - JCH OPTIMIZE ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive on

# cache.appcache needs re-requests in FF 3.6 (thanks Remy ~Introducing HTML5)
  ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest "access plus 0 seconds"

# Your document html
  ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 0 seconds"

# Data
  ExpiresByType text/xml "access plus 0 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/xml "access plus 0 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/json "access plus 0 seconds"

# Feed
  ExpiresByType application/rss+xml "access plus 1 hour"
  ExpiresByType application/atom+xml "access plus 1 hour"

# Favicon (cannot be renamed)
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 week"


# HTC files (css3pie)
  ExpiresByType text/x-component "access plus 1 month"

# Webfonts
  ExpiresByType application/font-ttf "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType font/opentype "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/font-woff "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/font-woff2 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 month"

  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header append Cache-Control "public"
  </IfModule>

</IfModule>

## END EXPIRES CACHING - JCH OPTIMIZE ##

########## Begin - Optimal default expiration time
## Note: this might cause problems and you might have to comment it out by
## placing a hash in front of this section's lines
<IfModule mod_expires.c>

# The below line was added from http://joomlaseo.com/Performance/use-browser-caching
# Should be safe to remove if it causes problems
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain text/html text/xml text/css application/xml application/xhtml+xml application/rss+xml application/javascript application/x-javascript


# Default expiration: 1 hour after request
ExpiresDefault "now plus 1 hour"

# 
ExpiresByType text/html "now plus 10 minutes"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "now plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "now plus 10 minutes"

# CSS and JS expiration: 1 week after request
ExpiresByType text/css "now plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "now plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "now plus 1 week"

# Image files expiration: 1 month after request
ExpiresByType image/bmp "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/gif "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jp2 "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/pipeg "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/tiff "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/vnd.microsoft.icon "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/ico "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/icon "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/ico "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/ico "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/vnd.wap.wbmp "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/vnd.wap.wbxml "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/smil "now plus 1 month"

# Audio files expiration: 1 month after request
ExpiresByType audio/basic "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType audio/mid "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType audio/midi "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType audio/mpeg "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType audio/x-aiff "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType audio/x-mpegurl "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType audio/x-pn-realaudio "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType audio/x-wav "now plus 1 month"

# Movie files expiration: 1 month after request
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType x-world/x-vrml "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType video/x-msvideo "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType video/mpeg "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType video/mp4 "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType video/quicktime "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType video/x-la-asf "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType video/x-ms-asf "now plus 1 month"

# Add correct content-type for fonts
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
AddType application/x-font-ttf .ttf
AddType application/x-font-opentype .otf
AddType application/x-font-woff .woff
# Fix for Woff 2 issue
AddType application/x-font-woff2 .woff2
AddType image/svg+xml .svg

# Compress compressible fonts
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf application/x-font-opentype image/svg+xml

ExpiresActive on

# Add a far future Expires header for fonts
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-opentype "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "now plus 1 month"

</IfModule>


# Compress all output labeled with one of the following media types.
#
# (!) For Apache versions below version 2.3.7 you don't need to
# enable `mod_filter` and can remove the `<IfModule mod_filter.c>`
# and `</IfModule>` lines as `AddOutputFilterByType` is still in
# the core directives.
#
# https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_filter.html#addoutputfilterbytype

<IfModule mod_filter.c>
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE "application/atom+xml" \
                                "application/font" \
                                "application/font-truetype " \
                                "application/font-ttf" \
                                "application/font-otf" \
                                "application/font-opentype" \
                                "application/font-woff" \
                                "application/font-woff2" \
                                "application/javascript" \
                                "application/json" \
                                "application/ld+json" \
                                "application/manifest+json" \
                                "application/rdf+xml" \
                                "application/rss+xml" \
                                "application/schema+json" \
                                "application/vnd.geo+json" \
                                "application/vnd.ms-fontobject" \
                                "application/x-font-ttf" \
                                "application/x-javascript" \
                                "application/x-web-app-manifest+json" \
                                "application/xhtml+xml" \
                                "application/xml" \
                                "font/eot" \
                                "font/ttf" \
                                "font/otf" \
                                "font/woff" \
                                "font/woff2" \
                                "font/opentype" \
                                "image/x-icon" \
                                "image/bmp" \
                                "image/svg+xml" \
                                "image/vnd.microsoft.icon" \
                                "image/x-icon" \
                                "text/cache-manifest" \
                                "text/css" \
                                "text/html" \
                                "text/javascript" \
                                "text/plain" \
                                "text/vcard" \
                                "text/vnd.rim.location.xloc" \
                                "text/vtt" \
                                "text/x-component" \
                                "text/x-cross-domain-policy" \
                                "text/xml"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  # For Olders Browsers Which Can't Handle Compression
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
  BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Could be a bad htaccess rule.  Can you post your .htaccess?

Comment: This post has been appropriately posted at JSE https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/23997/12352